# Node.js-TypeScript: Best practice to call external API asynchronously

Tags: node.js, typescript

In a Node.js app(written in TypeScript), an external API needs to be called when POST API(save data) is called. This external API is independent and should be running in the background without causing any delay in the response.

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: I'd say just make the call to the external API without waiting for it. Do you need the result of the external API call before returning data from your api?

Comment: Just synchronize your External API call inside your API post saved, for execution time it depends on the same function, the response time of the external API, begin with a functional solution and think about optimization later it really needs!

Comment: The result of the external API is not needed. Would it be a normal function call or any module is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others suggests in comment, just do not wait for the request to finish. How would you achieve that? You can make use of the native http module or a popular third-party module like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). I like using request. Here is an example using request:

```
const request = require('request');
app.post('/', async (res, res) => {
  request('http://www.google.com');

  res.send('Done with it');
})
```